Execution reverted using go-ethereum
When im using the remix ide (and in js with web3 lib) to interact with the smart contract there's no problem, but in golang with geth always return me "execution reverted" in call function (get method).
I'm compiling the .sol code with solc version 0.8.19 (abi + bin) and using abigen to generate golang code. If there's a way to debug or trace this error, please let me know. Ty
*goquorum private blockchain (geth)
sol file: https://gist.github.com/victor99z/e038acae67d7f928c4ace3fc9e8c7b4f
go main: https://gist.github.com/victor99z/8921aaf6eefcd497229fcc926b7ad7f2
go abigen: https://gist.github.com/victor99z/8cd9592fe3cf1014484898d1aff19dbd
Edit: So guys i found the problem, analyzing the request used by web3js and go, the field “data” in go request doesn't exist, it's used “input” instead. Downgraded my go-ethereum version from v1.14 to v.1.12 and solve this issue.

I can store values using Set function

In you contract. Try to only return the type instead of a name that does not exist.
  function get() view public returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }

This might work in JS as Javascript is less strict on types than Golang is.
Edit
You might want to add the constructor to your contract and see if this is helping.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.

Try with the constructor

Even with constructor i'm getting "execution reverted".

var SimpleStorageMetaData = &bind.MetaData{
ABI: "[{"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"retVal","type":"uint256"}]
Not sure if you updated your bindings but i still see this

I forgot to update the gist files sorry
